# Поиск URL в String. Java

Tags: java, строки, url

У меня условно есть строка:

```java
String text = "Привет, смотри: https://www.youtube.com/";
```

Мне нужен метод который разделит строку на `Привет, смотри:`  и `https://www.youtube.com/`

Не знаю как реализовать, найти какой-то способ не удалось.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если формат строки, содержащей URL, условно известен "<префикс><суффикс>", то можно составить регулярное выражение и выбрать в нём соответствующие группы.

Группы могут быть именованными в виде `(?<group_name>)`, или к ним можно обращаться по индексу, начиная с 1.

```java
public static void parseUrl(String text) {
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?<prefix>.*?)(?<url>https?://\\S+)(?<suffix>.*)", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
    
    Matcher m = pattern.matcher(text);
    if (m.find()) {
        System.out.printf("prefix: [%s]%n", m.group("prefix")); // m.group(1)
        System.out.printf("url   : [%s]%n", m.group("url"));    // m.group(2)
        System.out.printf("suffix: [%s]%n", m.group("suffix")); // m.group(3)
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("Неверный формат");
    }
}

// тесты
parseUrl("Привет, смотри: https://www.youtube.com/");
System.out.println("-----");
parseUrl("Привет, смотри: https://www.youtube.com/ как тебе?");
System.out.println("-----");
        parseUrl("https://www.youtube.com/ как тебе такое?");
```

Результаты

```
prefix: [Привет, смотри: ]
url   : [https://www.youtube.com/]
suffix: []
-----
prefix: [Привет, смотри: ]
url   : [https://www.youtube.com/]
suffix: [ как тебе?]
-----
prefix: []
url   : [https://www.youtube.com/]
suffix: [ как тебе такое?]
```

И префикс, и суффикс в данном формате являются необязательными, то есть, будут являться пустыми строками.

Comment: А можно ли получать так-же строку после URL?
Мол: prefix, url, suffix

Comment: Разумеется можно, тогда вам следует определить формат, по которому вы будете отделять "суффикс" от url'а, например, должен быть некий разделитель (пробел и/или знак пунктуации).  В представленном коде урлом считается последовательность, начинающаяся с "http://" или "https://", и НЕ содержащая пробельных символов (как минимум один не-пробельный).

Comment: Я попытался разобраться в этом и поискал но не нашёл как сделать, подскажите пожалуйста

Comment: Приведите пример

Comment: Как вы и сказали, чтобы разделителем был пробел.
`"Привет, смотри: https://www.youtube.com/ как тебе?"` Но главное чтобы суффикс был необязателен

Comment: @just_lofe, см. обновленный ответ

Comment: огромное спасибо за помощь, самому разбираться не время, задач много) потом как нибудь изучу эту тему