# Помогите с regex выражением

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения

Помогите пожалуйста составить выражение:

```
String input = "Префикс [строка, цифры] Суффикс";
```

Нужно всё привести в вид:

- Префикс
- строка
- цифры
- Суффикс

Comment: `(\w+)\s\[(\w+),\s(\w+)\]\s(\w+)`

Comment: Класс `\w` распространяется только на английский алфавит, цифры и подчёркивание, см. [документацию](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для кириллического алфавита потребуется использовать POSIX-класс `\p{L}` для букв (при использовании `find`), или же `\P{L}` для разбиения по не-буквам.

- Определяем слово как непустая последовательность букв `\p{L}+`, используем Stream API и метод [`Matcher::results`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase%2F9%2Fdocs%2Fapi%2F%2F/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#results--) (Java 9+) для получения потока совпадений

```java
String input = "Префикс [строка, цифры] Суффикс";

Pattern.compile("\\p{L}+").matcher(input)
    .results()                     // Stream<MatchResult> поток совпадений
    .map(MatchResult::group)       // Stream<String> поток слов
    .forEach(System.out::println); // печать каждого слова
```

- Аналогично, можно разбить строку по разделителям НЕ-буквам `\P{L}+` при помощи `String::split`

```java
Arrays.stream(input.split("\\P{L}+"))  // Stream<String>
    .forEach(System.out::println);
```

или же `Pattern.splitAsStream`:

```java
Pattern.compile("\\P{L}+").splitAsStream(input)  // Stream<String>
    .forEach(System.out::println);
```

---

Во всех случаях результат будет такой:

```
Префикс
строка
цифры
Суффикс
```

Comment: А можно как-то поделить на группы? И квадратные скобки нужны обязательно, в input строке

Comment: Так три месяца назад уже был [ваш аналогичный вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1524236/) с делением на группы и поиском префикса/суффикса.